# How to remove the space in lightning community?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-community

I'm doing community page with full width but this page had already space in my community page(Build you own(NOT Build your own LWC)). How can I remove this space from my community page?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a custom template for the community? Sorry, I'm not familiar with what the "Build Your Own" template gives you to start with. But I would start there seeing if you can modify the template. It will be an Aura component with this interface: `forceCommunity:themeLayout`